# Why does not WMI give correct result from a remote session?

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-remoting, sccm

I'm trying to query our sccm server with WMI.
This is working fine from a local session on the sccm-server computer :

```
PS>get-wmiobject -NameSpace "ROOT\SMS\site_CT1" -class SMS_ImagePackage | measure |select -expand count
20
```

but from a remote pssession nothing is returned

```
PS>  Enter-PSSession sccm-server
[sccm-server]: PS> get-wmiobject -NameSpace "ROOT\SMS\site_CT1" -class SMS_ImagePackage | measure |select -expand count  
0
```

The class can be listed remotly though it doesn't show any method or property

```
PS> get-wmiobject -computername sccm-server -NameSpace "root\sms\site_ct1" -List "sms_Imagepackage"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
NameSpace: ROOT\sms\site_CT1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Name                                Methods              Properties                                                 PSComputerName   
----                                -------              ----------                                                 --------------   
SMS_ImagePackage                                                                                                    sccm-server
```

Comment: @Kayasax What happens if you run `Get-WmiObject` without piping it to measure/select. No output?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen no output remotely